# Find the group with presentation $\langle x, y: xy=yx, x^5=y^3\rangle$.

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Here's the problem:

Find the group with presentation $\langle x, y: xy=yx, x^5=y^3\rangle$.

Here's my answer:

The group is commutative by the first relation, so every "word" is of the form $x^iy^j$ for $i,j \in \mathbb{Z}$. By the second relation we have $x^a y^b $ for $0 \leq a \leq 4$ and $b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence the group is  isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_5} \times \mathbb{Z}$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer can't be right, since multiplying any element in $ \mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z $ by $ 5 $ gives you something of the form $ (0, 5x) $, and such an element can't be divided by $ 3 $ in this group, so there's no element to play the role of $ y $.

To find the isomorphism class, note that there is a surjective map $ \mathbb Z^2 \to G $ given by $ (n, m) \to x^n y^m $  (where $ G $ denotes your group) whose kernel is precisely $ \langle (5, -3) \rangle $. In other words, we're trying to find the quotient $ \mathbb Z^2/\langle (5, -3) \rangle $.

This quotient is isomorphic to $ \mathbb Z $, as you can see by noting that $ (5, -3) $ and $ (3, -2) $ form a basis of $ \mathbb Z^2 $, so $ G \cong \mathbb Z $.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why my reasoning is incorrect?

Comment: @user736948 Your reasoning only proves that any element of $ G $ can be written in the form $ x^n y^m $ with $ n \leq 5 $, which is certainly correct. It doesn't prove that $ G $ is isomorphic to $ \mathbb Z/5\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z $. Concretely, the problem is that you don't know that the subgroups $ \langle x \rangle $ and $ \langle y \rangle $ intersect trivially, so you can't form an internal direct product on the basis of this information alone, and as my answer demonstrates in fact they don't intersect trivially. (You also don't know that $ \langle x \rangle \cong C_5 $, either.)

Comment: This is very helpful. Many thanks!

Comment: How do you conclude that the kernel is *precisely* $\langle (5, -3)\rangle$? It is clear that $\langle (5, -3)\rangle \subset \ker$. However, how do we know that nothing else belongs to the kernel?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani It follows from the definition of a group which has a given presentation. The kernel of the map $ F_2 \to G $ is obviously generated by $ x^5 y^{-3} $ and $ [x, y] $, so it factors through the abelianization $ \mathbf Z^2 $ where it just has kernel generated by $ x^5 y^{-3} $, i.e. $ \langle (5, -3) \rangle $.

Comment: @Starfall: Thank you, that makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Once you know the group is abelian, then your question can be converted into linear algebra. Namely, the given presentation tells you that your group is isomorphic to the kernel of the homomorphism $h : \mathbb Z^2 \to \mathbb Z$ given by $h(x,y) = 5x-3y$, in other words the kernel of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix}$, or to put it another way the solution set of the matrix equation
$$(x \quad y) \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix} = 0
$$
To determine what that kernel is you can convert the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 5 \\ -3 \end{pmatrix}$ into [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form), which gives the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
From this it now easily follows that the kernel is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score -1):

> Is this correct?

No.

```
gap> F:=FreeGroup(2);
<free group on the generators [ f1, f2 ]>
gap> rels:=[(F.1)*(F.2)*((F.1)^(-1))*((F.2)^(-1)), (F.1)^5*((F.2)^(-3))];
[ f1*f2*f1^-1*f2^-1, f1^5*f2^-3 ]
gap> G:=F/rels;
<fp group on the generators [ f1, f2 ]>
gap> P:=PresentationFpGroup(G);
<presentation with 2 gens and 2 rels of total length 12>
gap> TzGoGo(P);
#I  there are 2 generators and 2 relators of total length 12
gap> TzPrint(P);
#I  generators: [ f1, f2 ]
#I  relators:
#I  1.  4  [ 1, 2, -1, -2 ]
#I  2.  8  [ -2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -2, -2 ]
gap> Size(G);
infinity
gap> StructureDescription(G);
"C0"
gap>
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know where my reasoning breaks down?

Comment: I'm not sure, @user736948. I'm sorry.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Not me! Thanks anyway.